# Div not displaying when opened in Chrome browser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have  a website

[**Link-To-Website**](http://www.designmissionseries.com/index.html)

So when You open the link on the Chrome Browser the Div that hold the logos of different event on the right side does not appear,

But In you resize the browser it comes back .

Although  this does not happen in the Mozilla FIrefox

Can any one let me know where could be the problem

Thanks

Comment: please add an [mcve] to the question. It makes it easier to see what's going on

Comment: can tell you this that `CustomScrollbar` causing the problem and why images show on browser resize because `$(window).resize(function(event) {$('header').mCustomScrollbar("update");});`

Comment: the plugin CustomScrollbar is behaving wrong with your resizing script, maybe you are missing something on the `Responsive Functions` part of the code

Comment: @Frondor thanks for the headsUp I am gonna look into that , Actually it was ready made theme I bought , So have not much knowledge about it